# Increasing size of semi circle using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, charts

I am making a simple semi circle using react and css.

**Working Example:**

```js
const data = {
  "initial": {
    "unit": "GB",
    "value": 2
  },
  "remaining": {
    "unit": "GB",
    "value": 0.9
  },
  "type": "Internet",
};

function SemiCircleChart({min, max, value}){

  const angle = (value / max) * 180;
  const style = {'--angle': angle + 'deg'};

  return (
    <div class="sc-gauge">
      <div class="sc-background">
        <div class="sc-percentage" style={style}></div>
        <div class="sc-mask"></div>
        <span class="sc-value">{ value }</span>
      </div>
      <span class="sc-min">{ min }</span>
      <span class="sc-max">{ max }</span>
    </div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <SemiCircleChart
      min={0}
      max={data.initial.value}
      value={data.remaining.value}
    />,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```css
:root {
  --angle: 90deg;
}

body {
  background-color: #555888;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px
}

code {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #ccc
}

.sc-gauge {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.sc-background {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 150px 150px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.sc-mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #555888;
  border-radius: 150px 150px 0 0
}

.sc-percentage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: -200%;
  width: 400%;
  height: 400%;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #00aeef;
}

.sc-percentage {
  transform: rotate(var(--angle));
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.sc-min {
  float: left;
}

.sc-max {
  float: right;
}

.sc-value {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<code>
    This will be a part of the Simple Chart library.
</code>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I need to increase the size of the above chart both horizontally and vertically.

The things I have **tried**,

```
.sc-gauge {
   width: 400px; //Modified old values
   height: 400px; //Added height as new value
}
```

You can see in the above code that width is increased from `200px` to `400px` and height as `400px` newly added under `.sc-guage` and it expands the width but the height is not increased.

How to increase the size of the above given semi circle chart?

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, I did similar, mostly you should just try to set always height:50% of the width:

```css
.sc-gauge {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px; /*ADDED */ /* Should always be 50% of the width */
```

I would also suggest you to take out the min and max from `.scgauge`. as I added the `overflow:hidden;` in it.

### DEMO:

```js
const data = {
  "initial": {
    "unit": "GB",
    "value": 2
  },
  "remaining": {
    "unit": "GB",
    "value": 0.9
  },
  "type": "Internet",
};

function SemiCircleChart({min, max, value}){

  const angle = (value / max) * 180;
  const style = {'--angle': angle + 'deg'};

  return (
    <div class="sc-gauge">
      <div class="sc-background">
        <div class="sc-percentage" style={style}></div>
        <div class="sc-mask"></div>
        <span class="sc-value">{ value }</span>
      </div>
      <span class="sc-min">{ min }</span>
      <span class="sc-max">{ max }</span>
    </div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <SemiCircleChart
      min={0}
      max={data.initial.value}
      value={data.remaining.value}
    />,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```css
:root {
  --angle: 90deg;
}

body {
  background-color: #555888;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px
}

code {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #ccc
}

.sc-gauge {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px; /*ADDED */ /* Should always be 50% of the width */
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow-y:hidden; /* ADDED */
}

.sc-background {
  position: relative;
  height: 200%; /* ADDED */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0; /* MODIFIED */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.sc-mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #555888;
  
  /*ADDED */
  border-radius: 100%  100% 0 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: unset;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}

.sc-percentage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: -200%;
  width: 400%;
  height: 400%;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #00aeef;
  
  /*ADDED*/
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin-left:0;
}

.sc-percentage {
  transform: rotate(var(--angle));
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.sc-min {
  float: left;
}

.sc-max {
  float: right;
}

.sc-value {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%; /* MODIFIED */
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<code>
    This will be a part of the Simple Chart library.
</code>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I use this on my website, it works fine:

I made an example with different width, in the middle example. It is responsive based on the container size you would give, [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Maxigui/pen/ExVVZPG).

```css
#pieContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Set start position and size of the disc, max is 180deg */
.hold {
  
}

/* Set start position and size of the disc, max is 180deg */
.pie {
  
}

#pieSliceGreen{
  position: absolute;
  width: 98%;
  height: 196%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #c5c8cb;
  margin:1%;

  /* <top>, <right>, <bottom>, <left> */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 50%, 0 50%); 
}
/* If more than 180deg, a calcul must be done because if it would not go over 180deg
/* Set degree of the 1st answer which represent the % of the answer */
#pieSliceGreen .pie {
  background-color: rgb(91, 175, 25, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  /* <top>, <right>, <bottom>, <left> */
  clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 50%);
  /*clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 50%, 0 50%); 
*/
  -webkit-transform:rotate(160deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(160deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(160deg);
  transform:rotate(160deg);
}
/* Set white disc in the middle*/
#pieFrontground1{
  width: 93%;
  height: 186%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

/* Set degree as the previous #pieSlice + .pie */
#pieSliceRed {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 180%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #c5c8cb;

  /* <top>, <right>, <bottom>, <left> */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 50%, 0 50%);
  margin: 5%;
}
/* Set degree which represent the % of the answer */
#pieSliceRed .pie {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
    /* <top>, <right>, <bottom>, <left> */
  clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 50%);
  
  background-color: rgb(204, 71, 72, .8);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(50deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(50deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(50deg);
  transform:rotate(50deg);
}

#pieFrontground2{
  width: 83%;
  height: 166%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

/* Set degree as the previous #pieSlice + .pie */
#pieSliceRed2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 78%;
  height: 156%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #c5c8cb;

  /* <top>, <right>, <bottom>, <left> */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 50%, 0 50%);
  margin: 11%;
}
/* Set degree which represent the % of the answer */
#pieSliceRed2 .pie {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
    /* <top>, <right>, <bottom>, <left> */
  clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 50%);
  
  background-color: #20a8dc;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(100deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(100deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(100deg);
  transform:rotate(100deg);
}
#pieFrontground3{
  width: 73%;
  height: 146%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.pieFrontground {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:100%;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#lastFrontground{
  width: 20%;
  height: 40%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="pieContainer">
  <div class="pieBackground"></div>
    <div id="pieSliceGreen" class="hold"><div class="pie"></div></div>
     
  <div id="pieFrontground1" class="pieFrontground"></div>
  
    <div id="pieSliceRed" class="hold"><div class="pie"></div></div>
  <div id="pieFrontground2" class="pieFrontground"></div>
    <div id="pieSliceRed2" class="hold"><div class="pie"></div></div>
  <div id="pieFrontground3" class="pieFrontground"></div>
  <div id="lastFrontground" class="pieFrontground"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i see the error

```
    body {
  background-color: #555888;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px
}
```

You are limiting the body to 300px so it can't make the chart 400px.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
  "initial": {
    "unit": "GB",
    "value": 2
  },
  "remaining": {
    "unit": "GB",
    "value": 0.9
  },
  "type": "Internet",
};

function SemiCircleChart({min, max, value}){

  const angle = (value / max) * 180;
  const style = {'--angle': angle + 'deg'};

  return (
    <div class="sc-gauge">
      <div class="sc-background">
        <div class="sc-percentage" style={style}></div>
        <div class="sc-mask"></div>
        <span class="sc-value">{ value }</span>
      </div>
      <span class="sc-min">{ min }</span>
      <span class="sc-max">{ max }</span>
    </div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <SemiCircleChart
      min={0}
      max={data.initial.value}
      value={data.remaining.value}
    />,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```css
:root {
  --angle: 90deg;
}

body {
  background-color: #555888;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px
}

code {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #ccc
}

.sc-gauge {
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.sc-background {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 450px 450px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.sc-mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 380px;
  background-color: #555888;
  border-radius: 450px 450px 0 0
}

.sc-percentage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: -200%;
  width: 400%;
  height: 400%;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #00aeef;
}

.sc-percentage {
  transform: rotate(var(--angle));
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.sc-min {
  float: left;
}

.sc-max {
  float: right;
}

.sc-value {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<code>
    This will be a part of the Simple Chart library.
</code>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Try This!

You might want to change the thickness of the chart.

Comment: Can you give some brief of what css change you have made? Thanks..

Comment: @HelloWorld He was just modified height on `.sc-background`, `.sc-mask` and border-radius on `.sc-background` but as you can see the `.sc-percentage` is actualy wrong positionned. Because of the weird CSS you made there.

Comment: Yes, So I found that one of the elements was for the height and one for the width. If you look at the `.sc-gauge` is for the width and it is double what the height is. `.sc-background` is for the height.